# usage c++11 std::tuple in big projects

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, stdtuple

C++11 added very useful container std::tuple, now I may convert many structures to std::tuple :

```
// my Field class
struct Field 
{
     std::string path;
     std::string name;
     int id;
     int parent_id;
     int remote_id;    
};

//create
Field field = {"C:/", "file.txt", 23, 20, 41 };  

 //usage
  foo( field.path );
  field.name= new_name;
  int id = field.id;
```

to

```
//to std::tuple,               /--path,  /--name      /--id, /--parend_id,   /--remote_id
using Field = std::tuple< std::string, std::string , int,   int ,           int >;

//create
auto field = make_tuple<Field>("C:\", "file.txt", 23, 20, 41);      



// usage
     foo( std::get<0>(field) );  // may easy forget that the 0-index is path
     std::get<1>(field) = new_name; // and  1-index is name
     int id = std::get<2>(field);   // and 2-index is id, also if I replace it to 3, 
                       //I give `parent_id` instead of `id`, but compiler nothing say about.
```

But, here is only one disadvantage for using std::tuple in big projects - may easy forget what was meaning of each type of tuple, because here isn't access by name, only by index.

For that reason, I would use old  Field class.

**My question is that, Can I solve this disadvantage simple and beatiful?**

Comment: You could use an `enum` type to specify the indices and make the stuff more readable.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why you should **NOT** use tuples for cases like this!

Comment: What do you solve / what are the advantages of using *tuples* instead of structs?

Comment: Yes you can solve this beautifully [overloading the dot operator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy9ITl1AWRY). Easy!

Comment: Please, do NOT use tuples like this.

Comment: I voted to close this question: Please add sufficient details to better understand what you are really trying to solve.

Comment: I well describe what is disadvantage  of using std::tuple, and I want to solve this. That you do not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can solve the disadvantage both simply and beautifully:

*Use the right tool for the job!* In this case, structs or classes.

Tuples are not meant to replaces structs in cases like this. Just because you have a new and shiny hammer in your toolbox does not mean that you should now use it to cut wood.

Comment: To those that think that "std::get<0>(field)" is not as easy to read as "Field.path": it's easy to have tuples as easy to read as plain old struct: you only have to define your structs that way
struct Field 
{
     std::string $0;
     std::string $1;
     int $2;
     int $3;
     int $4;    
};
That way, everything will be as easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

Well, conceptually `tuple` and plain old `struct` are very similiar. The main difference is that members of `struct` are accessed using a name, while members of `tuple` are accessed using an index.

So it seems you want to use `tuple` as a struct - why not just use `struct`?

Comment: Because std::tuple is standard container and over it I can do many operations than struct, like std::make_tuple, std::tuple_cat, std::forward_as_tuple and etc. Also, I can iterate fields by index in variadic functions, which struct never.

Comment: Single words can say, std::tuple very useful with compile-time operations. Only one its disadvantage is that its members can't access by name.

Comment: Most of those things you mention you can already do with structs and classes. `make_tuple` is just the make idiom for an external constructor for your struct, which has existed forever. If you know your structs (why wouldn't you?) `my_struct_cat` is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enum to provide "field names":

```
enum FIELDS { path, name, id, parent_id, remote_id };
auto field = make_tuple<Field>("C:\", "file.txt", 23, 20, 41);      

foo( std::get<FIELDS::path>(field) );  // may easy forget that the 0-index is path
std::get<FIELDS::name>(field) = new_name; // and  1-index is name
int id = std::get<FIELDS::id>(field);
```

(After edit, I'm using a qualified version for the enums here because they are rather common field names, but it's not strictly necessary)

Comment: Why would you then use such meaningless names? Why don't you use names like `FieldPath`, `FieldName`, `FieldID` etc.?

Comment: well of course you would, but I don't know what the semantics of your fields are... Obviously you're supposed to use field names that match your purposes.

Comment: I simply reused the same names from the question... I don't understand why you invent new names if they have been given ;)

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't remember seeing the initial struct. Will edit

Comment: Please do not do this. You pretty much just reinvented structs with a much poorer syntax and no advantages whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should only use `tuple` for data that will be wrapped up and consumed within a few lines of each other, or when you actually have no knowledge of what the data is other than you need to package it together.  Sometimes both.

This makes it very useful for generic programming where you want to, say, package up some arguments and unpack them later.  Or, if you have a local lambda that you want to a sub-result out of and don't want to make a struct for it -- but even then, I'd be tempted with a struct.

A great use for `tuple` is to have your `struct` return a `std::tie` (a `tuple` of references) of its parameters via a `make_tie` method (and `const` version).  `tuple` writes things like a lexical `operator<` for you, and this results in bug resistant implementations of `<` and `==` and even `=` in some cases (where default equality isn't quite right, but you want to invoke default equality as a sub-problem).